# Typescript Decorators are not working as expected in React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, babeljs

I'm trying to use my own typescript dependency [ioc-service-container](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioc-service-container) in a react native typescript project.

The dependency uses typescript property decorators, like this:

```js
const service = new Service();
ServiceContainer.set('service', () => service);

class Foo {
  @inject
  service!: Service;
}
```

This works fine for reactJS, Vue & Node backends. But it does not work in react native. The property `service` from Foo is still undefined. After some debugging I found out, that the passed property to the `inject`-decorator is an empty object not the class Foo.

I think the problem is bable transforming my code ... but I'm not sure.

babel.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { 'legacy': true }], // required for @boundMethod decorator
  ],
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    // ...
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you every figure this out?

Comment: sadly no ... i'm using a workaround without decorators

Answer (score 0):

Use emitDecoratorMetadata:true on tsconfig file